# QtCreator build system is broken after OSX upgrade

Tags: c++, macos, qt-creator, osx-mountain-lion

I recently upgraded my OSX to mountain lion and ever since I cannot compile my project using Qt Creator anymore. I get bunch of errors like the following:

`/Users/user/codes/lib/io/xdmfWriter.cpp:63: error: explicit instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' but no definition available`

`/Users/user/codes/lib/io/xdmfWriter.cpp:-1: In instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]':`

`/Users/user/codes/lib/io/xdmfWriter.cpp:63: instantiated from here`

```
// xdmfWriter.cpp -- line 63:
gridName << xdmfName_ << "." << timeStep;
```

`gridName` is a `std::ostringstream` object and `xdmfName_` is a `std::string` variable declared as a private member of the `xdmfWriter` class and initialized in the class constructor. I did not have this problem before ... Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be fixed by adding a `c_str()` as in:

```
gridName << xdmfName_.c_str() << "." << timeStep;
```

However, this is not a permanent solution.

**Update:** I found the solution in https://web.archive.org/web/20140809210004/http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/19106/P15

You need to change `-mmacosx-version-min=10.5` in `$QTDIR/mkspecs/common/g++-macx.conf` to `-mmacosx-version-min=10.7`.
This is because SDKs for 10.5 or 10.6 are not included in Mountain Lion and XCode 4.4.

Comment: Ugh... I'm kinda stuck on this one.. where does QT dump all that stuff with a standard install?

Comment: You can run `qmake -v` to get the location fo your qt directory, for me that's `/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.4/lib`. The `mkspecs` directory will then be one level above that, or for my example, `/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.4/mkspecs`.

Answer (score 6):

I have tried changing the g++-macx.conf fila but I was still getting the errors. I found that using:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fpermissive
```

on my pro file did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like if I use the `Clang` toolchain (which forces `clang++` instead of `llvm-g++`) I do not have this problem ...

Comment: how did you do this? some option in QT Creator or something else?

Comment: @SamJarman Depends on QtCreator version. Before it was in the Qt version > toolchain. Withe the new release (2.6 I guess) the whole thing is changed to "kits" ...